# What is the correct git url to use for Bamboo for local repositories?

Tags: git, bamboo

I have a local git repository folder (not hosted on anything) that I want link to Bamboo but I don't know what the correct git url is.

I tried:

/e:/path/to/repo

/e:/path/to/repo.git

file:///e:/path/to/repo

file://e:/path/to/repo

But it doesn't work. I'm at lost what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a local Git repository, you'd have to choose 'Git' as the repository host type and add `E:\path\to\repo` (For Windows) and `/path/to/gitrepo` (for Linux based distros) as the Repository URL.

The screenshot below shows how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think I have tried that. I probably mistyped something.